# Can House Arryn be used under the rules of the base game?

Tags: variants, expansions, game-of-thrones

In the Feast for Crows expansion a new house (House Arryn) was introduced along with a new set of rules for a 4 player game that changed the way you scored victory points. Is it possible to use House Arryn (i.e. the cards and unit setup) with the normal Game of Thrones rules, or perhaps with the Dance of the Dragons expansion cards and setup? This could lead to some new ways to play 5/6 player games. Has anyone tried it or thought about it?

Answer (score 2):

Pypok made objective cards to play 6 player feast of crows style game of thrones:

http://enter-there.com/expansions/dance-with-dragons/